# OCaml unexpected type

Tags: ocaml

I have to write a function to remove elements from a lazy list. Indexes of elements to be removed are in list `xs`.

I don't know where I should sort xs? When I try in this way I get "Error: This expression has type...".

```
type 'a llist = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a llist)

let rec remove xs ll =
let rec helper = 
    function
    | (_, i, LNil) -> LNil
    | (h::t, i, LCons(x, xf)) -> if h = i then helper (t, (i + 1), xf())
                                 else LCons(x, fun() -> helper (h::t, (i + 1), xf()))
    | ([], i, LCons(x, xf)) -> LCons(x, xf)
in helper (List.sort xs, 0, ll);;
```

Comment: What's the rest of the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List.sort` from OCaml standard library has the following interface:

```
val sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

That means, that it accepts a function and a list. The function should have type `'a -> 'a -> int`, i.e., it takes two elements of arbitrary type `'a` and returns a value of type `int` that defines the mutual order of the arguments. The second argument is a list of values, where each value has type `'a`. A usual invocation of the sort function is:

```
List.sort compare [2;1;4;3]
```

So with this knowledge we can tackle with your program:

You invoke `List.sort` on `xs` this has two consequences:

1. type inference system concludes that `xs` is a function of type `'a -> 'a -> int`.
2. The result of `List.sort xs` is a function of type `'a list -> 'a list`. This is because, `List.sort` requires two arguments, but you provided only one.

Answer (score 0):

(List.sort xs) is a function that takes a list & returns a list - as xs is supposed to be the function that sorts the element of the list; you miss to pass a list as arg.

...whereas a list is expected.